# querying pg_stat_reset and pg_stat_user_tables between every step

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, usage-statistics

In my Java Batch, I would like to collect data from `pg_stat_user_tables` after each step.

For example, I want to collect the number of sequential scans for each table of each step from `pg_stat_user_tables`.

I tried this algorithm in java :

```
call pg_stat_reset()
Step 1
collect pg_stat_user_tables (or pg_stat_xact_user_tables) for Step 1
call pg_stat_reset()
Step 2
collect pg_stat_user_tables (or pg_stat_xact_user_tables) for Step 2
...
call pg_stat_reset()
Step n
collect pg_stat_user_tables (or pg_stat_xact_user_tables) for Step n
```

But the collected stats from tables are not uniform, and appears often in later steps than they should (tables scanned in step 2 appears in collected data from step 3 or later).

Do `pg_stat_user_tables` and `pg_stat_xact_user_tables` contain real time data?

Am I doing something wrong or is it impossible to collect real time data for each small step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statistics are not updated in real time, but collected and updated asynchronously by the *statistics collector* process.

If that is for debugging purposes, perhaps you can wait a couple of seconds after each step, then you have a good chance of getting current statistics.

For production use, I don't see the point of collecting statistics after each step.

Comment: Thank you. Yes indeed, it's for debugging purposes not for production.